# Hibernate  ClassFormatError..

Tags: java-ee, hibernate, java

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
Используюю Maven, Hibernate 4.0.0 final. В eclipse работает нормально, а в idea выдаёт эту ошибку... странно как-то pom.xml, hibernate.cfg.xml и UsersEntity.nbm.xml везде одинаковы. 
Есть класс UsersEntity

```
@Table(name = "users", schema = "", catalog = "ninjaway")  
@Entity  
public class UsersEntity {  
    private long userId;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "userId", nullable = false, insertable = true,   updatable = true, length = 20, precision = 0)  
    @Id  
    public long getUserId() {  
        return userId;  
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {  
        this.userId = userId;  
    }

    private String email;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 64, precision = 0)  
    @Basic  
    public String getEmail() {  
        return email;  
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {  
        this.email = email;  
    }

    private String pass;

    @Column(name = "pass", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 32, precision = 0)  
    @Basic  
    public String getPass() {  
        return pass;  
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {  
        this.pass = pass;  
    }

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 32, precision = 0)  
    @Basic  
    public String getName() {  
        return name;  
    }

    public void setName(String name) { 
        this.name = name;  
    }
```

HibernateTest

```
public class HibernateTest extends TestCase {  
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private UsersEntity user;  
    @Override  
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {  
        // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application  
        sessionFactory = new Configuration()  
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml  
                .buildSessionFactory();  
    }

    @Override  
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {  
        if ( sessionFactory != null ) {  
            sessionFactory.close();  
        }  
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })  
    public void testBasicUsage() {  
        // create a couple of events...  
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
        session.beginTransaction();

        List result = session.createQuery("from UsersEntity" ).list();  
        for ( UsersEntity user : (List<UsersEntity>) result ) {  
            System.out.println( "User: (" + user.getName() + ") : " + user.getEmail() );
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();  
        session.close();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: если проект мавеновский, причем тут ide?

Comment: без понятия, в eclipse почему-то работало, а в idea нет....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аллилуйя)) надо было всего лишь добавить

```
<dependency>  
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>  
     <version>4.2.0.Final</version>  
 </dependency>
```

в pom.xml